# TypeError: match() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python

Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:/Computing (Programming)/Code/name.py", line 3, in <module>
    valid = re.match("[0-9]","[0-9]","[A-Z]","[a-z]" ,tutorGroup)
TypeError: match() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

My code:

```
import re
tutorGroup = input("Enter your tutor group - e.g. 10: ")
valid = re.match("[0-9]","[0-9]","[A-Z]","[a-z]" ,tutorGroup)
if valid:
        print("OK!")
else:
        print("Invalid!")
```

I'm trying to search a string with a given parameter

Comment: What exactly do you want matched, `0-9` AND `A-Z` AND `a-z` or do you want them with OR, or something completely different?

Comment: I want it to be able to accept a 2 digit entry with two letters either upper or lower case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that `re.match` take 2 or 3 arguments, not 5. First the regex pattern, and the string to match. optionally it takes a 3rd argument with flags.
If you want to match a single digit or a letter, you would use `[0-9a-zA-Z]` as regex. If you want multiple letters or digits, you can use `[0-9a-zA-Z]+`. If you want a list of digits or a list of letters (but not mixed), you can use `([0-9]+)|[a-zA-Z]+`.

Edit: After reading your comment, the regex you want is `[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}`

Comment: I found the error! I needed to capitalize [a-z] to work. thanks pal

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.